# Dragging an object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an object that i want to drag in as3 but because its an object and not a movieClip or Sprite i cant drag it. Does anyone know why this is and how i can solve it? I tried to cast it as a Sprite but it doesnt work.

```
var order:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
order.startDrag();
```

So e.currentTarget gives me `[object Order]` and i cast it as a Sprite.

Anyone help how i could solve it?

Comment: What type does your `Order` class extend, if any?

Comment: Can you show the code for you `Order` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the answer to your own question. To use startDrag , your object must at least be a Sprite. If the Order class doesn't extend Sprite , casting the event currentTarget as Sprite won't achieve much.

You could implement your own solution, this way may be easier to debug...

```
    package
    {
         import flash.display.MovieClip;
         import flash.events.*;

         public class Order extends MovieClip
         {
             public function Order()
             {
                 this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , mouseDownHandler );

                 if( stage != null )
                    stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , mouseDownHandler );
             }

             private function mouseDownHandler ( event:MouseEvent ):void
             {
                 if( stage != null )
                    stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE , mouseMoveHandler );
             }

             private function mouseMoveHandler ( event:MouseEvent ):void
             {
                  this.x = mouseX;
                  this.y = mouseY;
             }

             private function mouseUpHandler ( event:MouseEvent ):void
             {
                 stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE , mouseMoveHandler );
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Well order is something i created in flash, i converted it to a movieclip and exported it. But when i trace it in flashbuilder it says [object Order] instead of movieclip

Comment: in that case Order extends MovieClip which is fine, so the problem maybe somewhere else. You could try implementing a MouseMove event listener and trace the results...